# How can I use selendroid and seleniumhq in same pom.xml?

Tags: java, android, maven, selenium, selendroid

I want to run in same time on PC browser and Mobile.
How can I use selendroid and seleniumhq in same pom.xml
I tried in my pom.xml to define dependencies like this

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.50.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.lightbody.bmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>browsermob-core-littleproxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0-beta-4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.selendroid</groupId>
        <artifactId>selendroid-standalone</artifactId>
        <version>0.17.0</version>
     </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.selendroid</groupId>
        <artifactId>selendroid-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.17.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

But I got those errors

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at catchmedia.objects.DriverObject.setUp(DriverObject.java:198)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:514)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:215)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:178)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:39)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:400)
at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$2.call(ThreadUtil.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/exec/DaemonExecutor
at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess.<init>(UnixProcess.java:52)
at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.<init>(CommandLine.java:38)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:161)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:644)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:138)
at catchmedia.objects.DriverObject.setUp(DriverObject.java:85)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:514)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:215)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:178)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:39)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:400)
at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$2.call(ThreadUtil.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

But when just using seleniumhq dependency and running just on browser, all is fine.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

try add:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-exec</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```